# Docker: redirect localhost:28015

Tags: docker, rethinkdb

I am trying to setup container for rethinkdb and another for nodejs.
I started rethinkdb container with:

```
docker run -itd --name test_rethinkdb -p 8080:8080 -p 28015:28105 -p 29015:29015 my_rethinkdb
```

Also, I am trying to setup second container with my nodejs app with:

```
docker run -itd --name test_nodejs --link my_rethinkdb:my_rethinkdb  my_nodejs.
```

But after `npm run start` command in test_nodejs container I see following

> message: ReqlDriverError: Could not connect to localhost:28015.

How can I redirect 127.0.0.1:28105 to my container with rethinkdb?

Comment: Please do not use `--link` it is depricated according to the official documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run it like below

```
docker run -itd --name test_nodejs my_nodejs
```

And your nodejs code should try to connect to `test_rethinkdb:28105` and not `localhost:28105`. When you run containers without specifying a network they are run the default bridge network.

In such cases the container can be identified using its id or its name. This name is what you passed using `--name`

PS: link option is now deprecated and should not be used